# Best way to learn Assembly Language outside of school?

Tags: assembly, binary, hardware

I've learned a number of languages such as C++, Java, C++ and some others and feel like I'm ready to learn assembly so I can fully understand everything. It's the closest thing I'm going to have to the hardware other than binary. But what is the best medium for learning Assembly without enrolling in a college course? I usually use YouTube to get me started then read about the details.

Comment: For your PC or any assembly language?

Comment: Read a book, e.g. [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html/) is a good one for `cisc` architecture and [Stack Overflow: How should I learn ARM assembly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270078/how-should-i-learn-arm-assembly) has some good pointers for `risc` architecture. Anyway, this question looks like off-topic on this site and it would be off-topic even on Programmers (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion is to learn Assembler by programming Atari 2600 games.  It's a fun exercise that will teach you a lot.  Download an emulator like Stella, spend a few hours with the documentation, and it's pretty easy to get started with basic stuff like creating and moving sprites.

This page has everything you need to get started.

http://atariage.com/2600/programming/

You get a lot of practice working in a very constrained programming environment (128 bytes of RAM!), so you're forced to do a lot of thinking.  Even once you've picked up enough to look at and understand others' source code, you'll learn a lot by seeing how others have ingeniously solved these problems.

Have fun!

Answer (score 2):

Believe it or not, YouTube has a very good set of tutorials on Assembly language.

Try this guy:  [YouTube Channel On ASM Tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/user/WhatsACreel/playlists)

(Disclaimer: No, I don't know him, and it's not my channel, etc.)

My  suggestion: Start with his "Practical x64 Assembly and C++ Tutorials"

There are others as well.  I chose this guy because I can understand his dalect of English when he speaks into the microphone.

I hope others will post more links if they find others.

Answer (score 1):

If u wanna learn assembly for more understanding of the programming,just open the  disassembly     window in your IDE and see how programs u have written in C and C++ transformed into assembly language. It's common way in reverse engineering and i find it interesting. 
Firstly,u got to understand the computer hardware structure and how it works and then after that assembly language becomes easy for u.